# Can not create connection JPA + MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans

[image: JPA Connection]

The problem is that I can't create a connection with jpa + mysql (5.5.27). I'm using netbeans 6.9.1 and the mysql connector.jar which is added correctly to the folder. But I get this error:

> "cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

What's the problem?

I cannot find the version the jar mysql 5.5

Comment: I have a better idea: do it by hand, don't let the IDE auto generate the code for you.

Comment: What is this picture says?

Comment: I think many people don't know Portuguese. So may be you translate.

Comment: Seems like a [bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197930).

Comment: What do you want me to translate? "Can not create connection Org.netbeans.modules.db.explorer.node.DriverListNode cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable" / Well do it by hand?? With a Framework its more easy. 

This problem will be, 'cause the version jar is not compatible or equal the mysql version in my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed leaving of to use netbeans 6.9.1 and using 7.2! HAHAH' this's great choice ;D

Apparently, it doesnt support more version recently of mysql! maybe :\